# Iphone 4 drain wifi 1 percent per minute

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone and it's jailbroken, running iOS 5.1. When using WiFi, it drains very quickly. The rate of discharge is about 1 percentage point every minute. Is this normal? Any suggestions? As usual, all push options are turned off, location services are off and only Safari is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems not ok to me. Does it still do that when it isn't jailbroken? If it does you should go to the Genius Bar and maybe get a replacement.

Maybe you could restore then put all your extra software on one by one to see which app is the likely cause.

Comment: Yeah. How about u whats d percentage of ur drain?

Comment: I would get 6-8 hours easily with wifi active, so 12% per hour, is about 0.2% per minute? That's a very rough guess.

Comment: My iPhone 4S lasts all day (up to 2), and I believe it's battery life to be shorter then the iPhone 4. Like @Adam Eberbach mentioned, try a reset. It drastically improved my battery life.

Comment: @user963499, have you also tried to shutdown and restart your iPhone? There may be an app that's running and consuming a lot of power in the background. From my experience with a 3GS running iOS 5.1, it can last well over a day if I'm just using Safari.

Comment: yeah. ive tried restarting it, doesnt work, im planning to reformat it and use ios 4 instead. what u guys think?

Comment: Don't rely on just turning push off, try temporarily just turning all your accounts off, especially any icloud ones.  Then see if it still happens.  For sure, it's almost certainly not wifi hardware, but something *using* the wifi that is causing rapid drain.

Comment: I ended up reformatting it, and it fix! Tnx