# iPhone 4 battery life on Wifi all day

Tags: iphone

I want to ask what is the average life of your iPhone 4 running iOS 5, with Wifi turn on, and what you are doing is just surfing through Safari. I'm getting 1 percent decrease every 3 minutes.

Comment: Is it jailbroken? Have you tried a hard reset? Does the advice in [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45597/3117) (and comments) help at all?

Comment: Yes its jailbroke . In fact it is freshly installed

Answer (score 5):

When actively browsing, that's not unusual.  1% every three minutes is 5 hours, which is expected if you've got the display on and using the wifi for browsing.

If it dropped 1% every three minutes with the display off, then you're likely running a background process that uses wifi and/or the GPS (turn by turn directions, running tracker, online streaming music, etc).

Comment: So in ur iphone4, you can browse for5 hrs straight? Tnx